# How to add x % noise in a signal in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, measurement, noise-generator

I am trying to add 5 % noise to a measured signal as follows (in MATLAB), but when I calculate percent of noise after addition, it is beyond +/- 5 % . Can you please tell me why this is the case ? Shouldnt it be within a +/- 5 % bound ?

```
 noiseSigma = 0.05 * signal;                % signal is my original signal
```

[image: signal]

```
noise = noiseSigma .* randn(1, length(signal));

noisySignal = signal + noise;
```

[image: Noise in signal]

```
percent_noise = 100*(noisySignal-signal)./signal;
```

[image: percent of noise in signal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

randn draws from a normal distribution so it can be larger than 1.

If you want to limit your noise to 5 percent you can try the following:

```
noise_limit = 0.05 * signal;
addative_noise = noise_limit .* (2*rand(1, length(signal))-1);
result = signal+addative_noise;
```

This works because rand chooses values between zero and one. multiply it by two and subtract one, and it chooses values between -1 and 1.

Comment: Thank you. But 'rand' will draw numbers within noise_limit with uniform distribution and not random distribution. Will it be appropriate to add noise with uniform distribution ?

Comment: @parag That depends on the application. If you want your noise to stay within a 5 percent band around the signal you can use a uniform distribution. You can also add noise drawn from  a normal distribution, but these are not limited to a band. Wikipedia has a list of all (many) distributions on bounded intervals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions